# Python 3 - How do you tell pipenv to use python 3 and not python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests, pipenv

I am trying to use the requests module, here is how I installed it:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx newslookup]$ pipenv install requests
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /var/www/html/newslookup/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python2 (2.7.14) to create virtualenv...
⠇ Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python2
  No LICENSE.txt / LICENSE found in source
New python executable in /home/ec2-user/.local/share/virtualenvs/newslookup-5acwuw4D/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /home/ec2-user/.local/share/virtualenvs/newslookup-5acwuw4D/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /home/ec2-user/.local/share/virtualenvs/newslookup-5acwuw4D
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Installing requests...
Adding requests to Pipfile's [packages]...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
✔ Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (ab273c)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (ab273c)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 5/5 — 00:00:01
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

Here is what it looks like when I run my script:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx newslookup]$ python3 nasdaq_scrape_sec.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nasdaq_scrape_sec.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

As you can see, the problem is that when I install it, it is using python 2 instead of python 3 `(Using /usr/bin/python2 (2.7.14))`

How can I tell pipenv to use Python 3 instead of Python 2?

Or is there a specific python 3 way of installing requests?

Comment: `pipenv --python 3.5` do `pipenv --help` for more help....

Comment: When you initiate Pipenv, you must make sure you specify the version. Changing Pipfile and specify the version is not recommend.

Comment: From the docs: To initialize a Python 3 virtual environment, run $ `pipenv --three`.

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way is to run (assuming you want `3.6`):

```
pipenv --python 3.6
```

---

Alternatively and as a more persistent solution, you can add the following lines into the pip file:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Comment: Hi Giorgos, where is this pip file located?  I am using Amazon Linux.

Comment: @BrentHeigold Normally,`Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` are created in the directory in which you've ran `pipenv`.

Comment: Hi Giorgos, I have updated the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, and run the command pipenv --python 3.7 install requests, and it installed successfully, and I still get the "no module named requests".  Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: @BrentHeigold Now try to run `pipenv install requests` in your pipenv.

Comment: I just uninstalled pipenv and re-installed it using "pip3 install pipenv" and now the pipenv command doesn't work, was that the right thing to do?

Comment: It now says "-bash: /usr/bin/pipenv: No such file or directory"

Comment: @BrentHeigold how about `brew install pipenv`?

Comment: I'm on Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 7):

While creating a environment ,Pipenv will automatically scan your system for a Python that matches that given VERSION.

```
pipenv --python VERSION
```

Comment: How is this not the best answer?!

Answer (score 4):

just call the pipenv from python3, it will do the job

```
 python3 -m pipenv install requests
```