# Python versions in my PC shows 2.7.17 instead of 3.8.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, windows-10

[image: cmd python version]

Yesterday I've been trying to install Python 3.8.5. I got the installer from the python website. My problem is that whenever I run `python --version` in the command line, it keeps saying, like in the image above, Python 2.7.17.

Today I also installed the Microsoft store package, and it's the same.

But running `py` apparently gives me the correct version 3.8.5. Does this mean that every python program I'll write will use the current version? That's what I currently want to make sure of.

As a side note also, I uninstalled all other python versions except 3.8.5 that I saw in my settings>Apps list. So, that adds to my confusion why running `python --version` would still show 2.7.17.

Maybe not as relevant, but I also have WSL2 enabled on my machine, I would like to install python to both. At the moment I'm focusing on the Windows10 part, but if there's a solution that will help both, that'll be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

[update]: adding `python3 --version` screenshot
[image: python3 --version]

[update]: yet another confusing part for me:

[image: py -V vs python -V]

- should I just let this be?
- Is this something I need to straighten up first before moving forward?
- are my python programs going to be ran in version `3.8.5` and not
  `2.7.17`?

Comment: did you try `python3 --version` in the terminal?

Comment: The problem is probably with the PATH, and `python` there, linking to `python2`

Comment: @AhmetTavli yes I did, thanks for that, I forgot to include it. updated my post

Comment: @Pat-Laugh I wish I understood all of that already :)

Comment: If I type in my terminal (I'm using mac) `python --version` the output is python 2.7.1. The default python version for most pc is `python 2.7.1` but I'm using `python-3.8` via virtual-environment. I suggest you to same. Just install `python-3.8.5` via virtual-environment. I believe your problem will be solved.

Comment: @AhmetTavli you mean something like `pipenv` like in the other comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know my answer is very late but i see a lot of people facing this problem. So if you want to interact with the latest Python version in your command prompt, you just need to set newer (or which one you want) Python path variable above/before other Python version's path variables. This solution also helped me a lot with other path problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your `PATH` environment variable being set incorrectly. I'm guessing that you installed `Python 3` globally, after you had `Python 2.7` installed. Whenever you do this and have the option `Add to PATH` checked, it will overwrite the default python location to the new install, thus causing `Python 3` to now open instead. You can change this back manually by changing the value in `PATH`.

I'd suggest using something like `pipenv` to manage your python versions and respective libraries, that will create a sandbox for your application to run in and will always point to the correct dependencies.

Comment: I did check that option `add to PATH` upon installation of `3.8.5` but the `--version` command still gives me `2.7.17`. you mentioned `pipenv`, I honestly have no idea how to do this part, I've seen it in other docs I read, but I'm fairly new to programming, could you point me to where I might be able to follow a guide of sorts.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that's the case. If you want your default python to still be 2.7, go to your environment variables, and edit the `Path` variable and change where it says `C:\wherever_your_py3_install_root` to `C:\Python27`. Do this for the Scripts folder as well, make sure it points to `C:\Python27\Scripts`

Once you use `pipenv` a few times you'll remember how to do everything. It's fairly straight forward. Check out these 2 pages:


https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186765/python-3-how-do-you-tell-pipenv-to-use-python-3-and-not-python-2

Answer (score 1):

[image: py -V and python -V now showing same result]

Ok, so hopefully this fixes every question I had. Hopefully comments will assure me that is so.

What I did was, delete the environment variables relating to Python 27. Found the Python3.exe path and added that to the path variable. Not exactly sure how that works, but it did give me the outcome I wanted to see.